# Check the content of tinymce (v4) is empty or whitespace only

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Here is my code:

```
var content = tinymce.get('post_content').getContent();
if(($.trim(content)).length==0 || content == '' || /^(?:\s|<br *\/?>)*$/.test(content)) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
```

This code work fine when i set init tinymce:

```
'force_p_newlines' => false,
'force_br_newlines' => false,
'forced_root_block' => '',
```

Any better solutions? Because when i set forced_root_block is null, i can't use the button aligncenter,alignleft,alignright,...

Answer (score 0):

This can easiliy be done.
The following code snippet checks for the editor textcontent:

```
var body = tinymce.editors[0].getBody();

var textcontent = body.textContent;
textcontent = textcontent.replace(/^[ \s]+|[ \s]+$/ig, '');

if (!textcontent.length) alert("Content is empty!");
```

Comment: hi @Thariama: how can i can a specific tinymce? because i use mutiple editors in one page.
FYI: use can enter whitespaces then they press enter so the content value now is e.g: " &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br> "